# How to get selected checkboxes value using JQuery and Javascript and based on returned value show/hide divs

Tags: checkbox, hide, show

So I have a multiple choice question that I need to show/hide a div based on checkboxes. If 1 box is checked show this div, if 2 boxes are checked show previous div and add another, etc. I decided to do this based upon the value of each checkbox and then output its length. I have it working sort of. When I click the choices they work up until the 3rd response then it fails. Also if one checks from one of the bottom choices it skips the first div response. I think I am almost there but am stuck. Any help is appreciated.

```
<style>
.sd_response {

  border: #00749F double;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #FFF;
  width: 840px;

}
</style>

<script src="http://dunxoft.com/survey/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
//hide responses
$(".sd_response").hide(); 

$("input[name='name_3[]']").click(function() {
        getValueUsingParentTag();
    });

    function getValueUsingParentTag(){
    var chkArray = [];

    /* look for all checkboes that have name_3[] attached to it and check if it was checked */
    $("input[name='name_3[]']:checked").each(function() {
        chkArray.push($(this).val());
    });

    /* we join the array separated by the comma */
    var selected;
    selected = chkArray.join(',') + ",";

    /* check if there is selected checkboxes, by default the length is 1 as it contains one single comma */
    if(selected.length <= 2) {
        $("#q3response1").slideDown('fast');    
    } else {
        if(selected.length = 3 < 4) {
        $("#q3response2").slideDown('fast');
        alert (chkArray);
    } else {
        if(selected.length > 4) {
        $("#q3response3").slideDown('fast');
        }
    }
    }
}

// end function
}); 
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div>
<h3>Question 3 <span style="font-size: 0.6em; color: red;">required</span></h3><br>
<div style="font-size: 1.1em;"><p class="MsoNormal">You have experienced how many of the following:&nbsp;</p></div>

<p><input data-percent="70" name="name_3[]" value="8" type="checkbox"> Walked from one room to the next, only to forget why you’re there </p>
<p><input data-percent="50" name="name_3[]" value="9" type="checkbox"> You feel “off” and have been short with those trying to help you</p>
<p><input data-percent="20" name="name_3[]" value="10" type="checkbox"> You feel unsure that you can drive with your baby in the car</p>
<p><input data-percent="30" name="name_3[]" value="11" type="checkbox"> It takes you longer than 20 minutes to fall asleep</p>
<p><input data-percent="10" name="name_3[]" value="12" type="checkbox"> You have difficulty sleeping when your baby sleeps</p>

</div>


<div id="q3response1" class="sd_response"><p><strong>Answer for 1-2: </strong> It sounds like you may need to focus on getting a nap each day while your baby sleeps. </p>
</div>

<div id="q3response2" class="sd_response"><p><strong>Answer for 2-4:</strong> You are definitely lacking sleep. Make sure that you are getting as much sleep at night as possible. If you have a partner at home, split the night shift so that you can get 6 solid hours of sleep at night, and take additional naps during the day to help your body get as much rest as possible. Know that just one sleepless night can impair your judgment and reflexes as much as a blood alcohol level of 10 percent-which is equivalent to approximately 4 glasses of wine.   </p>
</div>

<div id="q3response3" class="sd_response"><p><strong>Answer for 4+:</strong> You are definitely sleep deprived. Make sure that you are getting as much sleep at night as possible. If you have a partner at home, split the night shift so that you can get 6 solid hours of sleep at night, and take additional naps during the day to help your body get as much rest as possible. Just one sleepless night can impair your judgment and reflexes as much as a blood alcohol level of 10 percent-which is equivalent to approximately 4 glasses of wine.
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) You are checking the length of `selected` ->

```
 if(selected.length <= 2) {
```

but since `selected = chkArray.join(',') + ",";` your length(/count) will always be off due to the `,`.

(2) In you `else`, you are setting `selected.length = 3` and then checking if it is less then `4`, which will always be true ->

```
if(selected.length = 3 < 4) {
```

try updating your function to something like ->

```
function getValueUsingParentTag(){
    var chkArray = [];

    /* look for all checkboes that have name_3[] attached to it and check if it was checked */
    $("input[name='name_3[]']:checked").each(function() {
        chkArray.push($(this).val());
    });

    /* we join the array separated by the comma */
    var selected;
    selected = chkArray.join(',') + ",";

    /* check if there is selected checkboxes, by default the length is 1 as it contains one single comma */
    if(chkArray.length <= 2) {
        $("#q3response1").slideDown('fast');    
    } 
    else if(chkArray.length <= 4) {
        $("#q3response2").slideDown('fast');
    } 
    else if(chkArray.length > 4) {
        $("#q3response3").slideDown('fast');
    }
}
```